# Problems with converting .data files to .c

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-prompt, python-2.x

Title.

I should probably tell you that I'm trying to convert the file via the Windows Command Prompt. [The error in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4wuj.png)

And this is the code in question:

Line 51:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  if len(sys.argv[1:]) == 0:
    usage()
    sys.exit
else:
  main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Line 19:

```
for i in range(0, (320*120) / 8):
  val = 0
```

What's wrong with this picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in line 19, you are trying to use a float number ((320*120)/8) as a parameter. since the range function creates a list, the last index cant be a non-integer so it throws an error. to fix that, simply conver the result to an integer using `int((320*120)/8)` or use integer devision using `(320*120)//8`

Answer (score 0):

Even though you tagged the question as Python 2.7, it is apparent that you are really using Python 3.x because only in Python 3.x would the division operator `/` produce a floating number from integer operands, in which case you should use the `//` operator instead to produce an integer result for use in `range`:

```
for i in range(0, (320*120) // 8):
```

Or if you want to be compatible with Python 2.7, you can do:

```
for i in range(0, int(320*120 / 8)):
```